# Flag an implemented feature through property or interface?

Tags: c#, architecture

Today at work we had a discussion how it would be better to implement a feature which have about 50% of the classes which implements a feature.

Solution 1: Using a property as flag

```cs
public interface Foo
{
   bool HasFeatureX { get; }
   void FeatureX();
   void OtherMethod();
}
```

Solution 2: Separate the interface and check whether a class implements a specific interface

```cs
public interface Bar
{
   void OtherMethod();
}
public interface Foo
{
   void FeatureX();
}
```

I prefer solution 2, because it has no overhead.

Are there any arguments for solution 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would argue that second solution is cleaner and better corresponds to the SOLID principles, especially the "Interface segregation" one (also based on the comments to the other answer it seems that to be useful in your case `IFoo` should implement `IBar`).

Note that there is another option (inspired by composition over inheritance approach) which can allow better code reuse in case when there are a lot of features and different implementations for the base interface:

```cs
public interface ISomeBaseInterface : IHaveFeature
{
   void SomeBaseMethod();
}

public interface IHaveFeature
{
   T? GetFeature<T>() where T : class; // or bool TryGetFeature<T>(out T? feature)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, argument No1: why would you define an interface with a field defined?

The second solution is much cleaner, one interface per concern, only defines abstract methods, i would go with solution 2 without a lot of argument as a cleaner practice, allthough it might need some more time to write.

Everyone implements what is needed only and no fields are in place.
To be more precise, name the interfaces after the features they are supposed to implement and you should be good to go

Comment: As an added comment, to make a "feature-flag" you would actually have a different configuration, both integrations available on your code and you would branch off depending on that application-wide config. For example a "doNewDepositFlow" setting on the application would tell you to call an implementor of Bar or Foo respectivly

Comment: We work with a DI container, so we would just replace the registered class. But some classes have the feature and some not.

Comment: You will still be working with a DI container. In a "service/handler" class you inject
AppSettings, FooImplementor, BarImplementor.

Depending on AppSettings.SomeFeatureBoolFlag, you would call one or the other.

The first solution is not a proper solution. 
FeatureX and OtherMethod are irrelevant, its not like its Foo.SomeMethod or Bar.SomeMethod.

You need to do 2 different things, if i get your code correct, so the 2nd solution is the only "proper" solution, the first one is a hacky